# AR implementation in flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality

I need to implement AR in a Flutter application and also support the web. What are the best ways to implement AR in Flutter, and are those methods also supported on the web?

I tried using 3D model viewers to show a model on the camera screen for a very simple start.
I read some articles about AR in Flutter by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Best ways to implement AR in Flutter**

There are two main ways to implement AR in Flutter:

1. **Using the ARCore and ARKit plugins:** These plugins provide native AR functionality for Android and iOS devices, respectively.
2. **Using a web-based AR library:** This approach allows you to create AR experiences that can be viewed on any device with a web browser.

**Support for the web**

The ARCore and ARKit plugins are not supported on the web, so if you want to create a web-based AR experience, you will need to use a web-based AR library.

**3D model viewers**

3D model viewers can be used to display 3D models on the camera screen, but they do not provide any AR functionality.

**Recommended approach**

If you need to implement AR in a Flutter application and also support the web, I recommend using a web-based AR library. This will allow you to create a single AR experience that can be viewed on any device, including mobile devices, desktop computers, and laptops.

**Web-based AR libraries**

There are a number of web-based AR libraries available, such as:

- A-Frame
- AR.js
- three.js

**Getting started**

To get started with web-based AR in Flutter, you can follow the steps below:

1. Create a new Flutter project.
2. Add a web-based AR library to your project.
3. Create a new Flutter widget that uses the web-based AR library to display your AR experience.
4. Run your Flutter application in a web browser.

**Example**

The following code shows an example of a simple Flutter widget that uses the A-Frame web-based AR library to display a 3D model of a cube:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ArCube extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AScene(
        children: [
          AEntity(
            geometry: ABoxGeometry(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1),
            material: AStandardMaterial(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To run this example, you would first need to add the A-Frame package to your Flutter project. You can do this by adding the following line to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  a_frame: ^3.1.2
```

Once you have added the A-Frame package, you can run your Flutter application in a web browser. To do this, run the following command in your terminal:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

This will open a new Chrome browser window with your Flutter application running.

**Conclusion**

Web-based AR libraries provide a way to create AR experiences that can be viewed on any device with a web browser. This makes them a good choice for Flutter developers who need to implement AR in their applications and also support the web.